# How to change the default title tag in Foundation 6?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

The default title tag is `<title>Foundation for Sites</title>` after running terminal command `npm start` or `npm run build`.

Is it possible to have the title tag output `<title>MY WEBSITE TITLE</title>` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be using the Basic Template.  Utilize the Zurb Advanced Template instead.  It's got nifty Handlebars templating and other goodies.  And it's the one Zurb uses with their client work.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html

Once you download & extract the advanced template, open `src\layout\default.htm`.  Update the title tag.

Zurb 6 uses [Panini](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html) to generate the page.  So you could separate out title to a `{{ title }}` variable.

Comment: Oh `src\layout\default.htm`, ok! I completely missed the part on Panini when I first started reading through the Foundation docs. Foundation makes a whole lot more sense now that I know Panini is a thing. Thanks!